# Calculation of the average memory access time based on the following data?

Tags: caching, operating-system, paging, tlb

Consider the following information

- Assume the cache is physically addressed
- TLB hit rate is 95%, with access time = 1 cycle
- Cache hit rate is 90%, with access time of again = 1 cycle
- Page fault is 1% and occurs when miss occurs in both TLB and Cache
- The TLB access and cache access are sequential
- Main memory access time is 5 cycles
- Disk access time is 100 cycles
- Page tables are always kept in main memory

What will be the Average memory access time based on the following information ?

**My Approach** => I am giving my approach of how i understood this question. Please check it.

**Average memory access time**

==>

```
Probability of NO page fault (Memory access time) 
+ 
Probability of page fault (Page fault service time)
```

==>

0.99 ( TLB hit **(TLB access time + cache hit + cache miss)** + TLB miss **(TLB access time + Page table access time + cache hit + cache miss)** )

+

0.01 (TLB access time + page table access time + Disk access time)

==>

0.99 ( 0.95 **(1 + 0.90(1) + 0.10(1 + 5)**) + 0.05(**1 + 5 + 0.90(1) + 0.10(1 + 5**)))

+

0.01 (1 + 5 + 100)

Is the given expression correct ?

Please let me know, that, is my approach right or have i committed some mistakes?

Can Anyone help me ?

**PS : I am having my mid term next week and need to practice such questions**

Comment: Man, are you being subjected to busywork pain.

Comment: What are 0.99 and 0.01 in your numbers?

Comment: @Ivan, 1% is the page fault. Hence, i used 99% for no page fault.

Comment: @Willturner in case of page fault, why don't you include 1 cycle for cache try time?

Comment: @Ivan, it is just 1 cycle. Even if i add it, it will not change the result much .Actually, my professor told me that answer comes 3 cycles, but i m getting some 4 cycles, thats why i think i am commiting some mistake.Can you answer this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the tricky line is `cache is physically addressed` meaning before hitting it we must perform the translation (as programs use virtual addresses)

I build the following probability tree to compute the average. We will be reducing it from leaves to calculate the whole average. Rules are super easy: we calculate branch costs and multiply them by the probability pretty much like you did in your calc. The value I get is **2.7225**

## Tree

[image: complete tree]

## 1st leave reduction, page fault

[image: reduction 1]

## after the reduction

[image: after the reduction]

## cost for cache hit scenario

Note: that we pay 1 cycle for cache access anyway

[image: cache hit scenario cost]

## before last reduction

Note: we pay 1 cycle for TLB anyway

[image: before last reduction]

```
1 + 0.95*1.5 + 0.05*5.95 = 1 + 1.425 + 0.2975 = 2.7225
```

Comment: Yes, you have got the answer right . Just a doubt, why are u having page fault by 2 types in the first tree . In the question, it is given that PF occurs when there is a miss both in TLB and cache ?

Comment: @willturner yeah, that's an error. If we have page in TLB, it means we have it in main memory, meaning no page faults on read, thanks for that

Comment: Corrected that. Now the avg time is larger by 0.01 :)

Comment: Salute. Very nice explaination. Thanks and its cleared now !!

Comment: I am going to use this method for all such questions and even in exam :)